# CMake to compile java code

Tags: java, cmake

Is it possible to use CMake to compile and run java code?

From command line the commands that I write on terminal is:

javac -classpath theClasspath mainClass.java

java -classpath theClasspath mainClass

If so, could you please give me an idea of how this can be achieved?

PS: I do not want to generate a jar file; just to compile the java class and if possible to run it.

Thanks.

**Update**: I have changed the command. I do not know why the additional text was not displayed. It might be because I used "<" and ">".

Comment: It's unclear what you've tried, or what you're using to compile at the moment. The command you've given is incomplete on its own.

Comment: normally to compile java, you would do: `javac SomeJavaSourceFile.java` and this will generate your `.class` file. Then to run it, : `java SomeJavaSourceFile` <-- notice I left off the `.class` part.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. However, I am asking whether it is possible to compile and run a java class using CMake

Comment: Why would you even do this... what's wrong with ant or maven?

Comment: Because I am trying to integrate a tool written in Java into another tool written in C++. In order to do this, I have written a binding class that instantiates the JVM, finds the main java class and invokes the required java method. Now, I need to find what code I need to write to compile everything together and where I should insert it in order to compile the whole project.

I've done this using a simple makefile and a shell script. However, the core tool (C++ software) uses CMake to build the executables.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

CMake has somewhat limited support for compiling Java code and executing Java class files.

The standard module [FindJava](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindJava.html) can be used to find a JDK installed on the local machine. The standard module [UseJava](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html) provides a few functions for Java. Among those is a function  `add_jar` to compile Java source files to a jar file.

Here is a small example that demonstrates how to use `add_jar`. Given the Java sample source file `HelloWorld.java`:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

The following CMake list file will compile `HelloWorld.java` to a jar file `HelloWorld.jar` and also add a CMake test that runs the jar with the JVM:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)

enable_testing()

project (HelloWorld NONE)

set(CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS "-source" "1.6" "-target" "1.6")

add_jar(HelloWorld HelloWorld.java)

get_target_property(_jarFile HelloWorld JAR_FILE)
get_target_property(_classDir HelloWorld CLASSDIR)

message(STATUS "Jar file ${_jarFile}")
message(STATUS "Class compiled to ${_classDir}")

add_test(NAME TestHelloWorld COMMAND ${Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE} -cp ${_jarFile} HelloWorld)
```

The CMake variable `CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS` can be used to specify compile flags. As a side effect the `add_jar` command will set target properties `JAR_FILE` and `CLASSDIR` that can be used to obtain the path to the generated jar file and the compiled class files directory, respectively.