# build a java opencv application using cmake

Tags: java, opencv, ant, cmake

I have already install opencv3.1 for java and I can found the opencv .jar. Now I want to write a simple test program, eg., display a image, but dont know how to write the CMakeLists. I found some examples using Ant, or sbt, but no cmake examples.

I am new to java, used C++ a lot before. I know how to link the opencv lib in cmake for c++ but dont know how to do it for java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake to compile java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985726/cmake-to-compile-java-code)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that and used it for a simple program, but I don't know how to add another library like opencv into it.